# Can I avoid "rightward drift" in Haskell?

Tags: coding-style, haskell

When I use an imperative language I often write code like

```
foo (x) {
    if (x < 0) return True;
    y = getForX(x);
    if (y < 0) return True;

    return x < y;
}
```

That is, I check conditions off one by one, breaking out of the block as soon
as possible.

I like this because it keeps the code "flat" and obeys the principle of "end
weight". I consider it to be more readable.

But in Haskell I would have written that as

```
foo x = do
    if x < 0
        then return x
        else do
            y <- getForX x

            if y < 0
                then return True
                else return $ x < y
```

Which I don't like as much. I could use a monad that allows breaking out, but
since I'm already using a monad I'd have to `lift` everything, which adds words
I'd like to avoid if I can.

I suppose there's not really a perfect solution to this but does anyone have
any advice?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why the `do`-block and `return`s at all? To me it would seem the conversion of this code would be non-monadic.

Comment: @stutsmith Oh, well just cause of `getForX` is monadic, i guess.

Comment: OK, well I've added my non-monadic solution as an answer anyway, just for reference.

Comment: On the third line in your haskell version I think you want `then return True`.

Comment: The first do is unnecessary and ugly

Comment: @monadic Oh ha you're right -- I just put it there instinctively whenever I get into a "monadic" mindset. But why would someone named "monadic" complain about an extra `do`? :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For your specific question: How about dangling `do` notation and the usage of logic?

```
foo x = do
  if x < 0 then return x else do
  y <- getForX x
  return $ y < 0 || x < y
```

#### Edit

Combined with what hammar said, you can even get more beautiful code:

```
foo x | x < 0     = return x
      | otherwise = do y <- getForX x
                       return $ y < 0 || x < y
```

Comment: These are all good answers but the "dangling do" I think will help me the most.

Comment: Because, while beautiful, the second code fragment doesn't answer the Owen's question: how to flatten several nested ifs.  Also, wow, I would have guessed that to be a syntactic error.  @Owen, I suppose it's a matter of preference, but I think the first fragment hides the structure of the computation: you can't immediately tell how the condition affects the rest of the code.  If you can't use a short-circuiting monad (I usually write a monad instance for Either which stops on the first Left), the large if is probably a better idea.

Comment: @scvalex It's an exception in GHC's parser. IIRC, it will only work with `do` and possibly `proc`.

Comment: @FUZxxl: In [section 2.7 of the Haskell report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch2.html#x7-210002.7), the layout rules are defined such that the non-brace lexeme _immediately following_ a `where`, `let`, `do` or `of` determines the indentation level. So this not GHC-specific, but part of the standard, even Haskell 98.

Answer (score 12):

Using patterns and guards can help a lot:

```
foo x | x < 0 = return x
foo x = do
    y <- getForX x
    if y < 0
        then return True
        else return $ x < y
```

You can also introduce small helper functions in a `where` clause. That tends to help readability as well.

```
foo x | x < 0 = return x
foo x = do
    y <- getForX x
    return $ bar y
  where
    bar y | y < 0     = True
          | otherwise = x < y
```

(Or if the code really is as simple as this example, use logic as FUZxxl suggested).

Answer (score 8):

The best way to do this is using guards, but then you need to have the `y` value first in order to use it in the guard. That needs to be gotten from `getForX` wich might be tucked away into some monad that you cannot get the value out from except through getForX (for example the `IO` monad) and then you have to lift the pure function that uses guards into that monad. One way of doing this is by using `liftM`.

```
foo x = liftM go (getForX x)
  where
    go y | x < 0     = True
         | y < 0     = True
         | otherwise = x < y
```

Answer (score 3):

Isn't it just

```
foo x = x < y || y < 0 where y = getForX x
```

EDIT: As Owen pointed out - getForX is monadic so my code above would not work. The below version probably should:

```
foo x = do
  y <- getForX x
  return (x < y || y < 0)
```

Comment: Well it would be except that getForX is monadic.

Comment: The logic's a little different though, since `getForX` is always "called" regardless of the value of `x`.