# Haskell 'else' parsing error

Tags: parsing, haskell, if-statement

I'm having an parsing error on the input 'else' but I have no idea how to solve it. I'm still new to this haskell thing.

```
depot = 
do
putStr ("Enter deposit amount: ")
deAmount <- getLine
let redeAmount = read deAmount
if redeAmount > 0 then 
    let accBal = redeAmount + accBal
    else 
        putStrLn "Please enter amount greater than 0"
```

Comment: As much as I remember from Haskell, this seems like an indentation error. Not sure though...

Comment: It doesn't seem like you have really understood the concept of functional programming yet. Perhaps you should go through a few tutorials, or use another language.

Answer (score 11):

The first mistake is that the `do` (and everything after it) needs to be indented.

The next mistake is that syntactically `let accBal = redeAmount + accBal` can't stand on its own like that. Either it needs to be followed by an `in` or it must be directly inside a `do` block (being inside an `if` which is inside a `do` block does not count).

However even if you fix the syntax, it won't do what you want. You can't use `let` to reassign variables. As a matter of fact you can't reassign variables at all. If you fix the syntax of your `let`, it will simply create a new variable `accBal` which will shadow the old variable `accBal`. The scope of that new variable will be the `then`-block of the `if`. Once you leave the `if`-block, you'll `accBal` will again refer to the old value of `accBal` no matter what you did inside the `if`.

So to fix your issue, you need to restructure your logic, so it doesn't depend on `accBal` being reassigned.

Comment: I would have thought that the stuff after the `do` had to be indented but it turns out this is not the case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7008493/can-i-avoid-rightward-drift-in-haskell/7008755#7008755 also http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Indentation#Indent_to_the_first (the `do` does have to be indented, though).

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much to add onto sepp2k's answer, but I thought I'd show you how I might write it:

```
type Balance          = Float               -- The type of the money balance
type TransactionT m a = StateT Balance m a  -- Something that modifies a balance
type Transaction a    = TransactionT IO a   -- Something that interacts with IO
                                            --  *and* modifies balance

-- Request the user to enter a deposit
getDeposit :: Transaction ()
getDeposit = do
 putStr "Enter deposit amount: "  -- You don't need () around the argument

 amountStr <- liftIO getLine  -- This is a consequence of using monad
                              -- transformers

 let amount = read amountStr

 if amount > 0
   then modify (+ amount) -- Update the balance
   else liftIO $ error "Please enter amount greater than 0." -- Raise an
                                                             --  exception
```

Here's a great little tutorial: http://learnyouahaskell.com/.

Here are some sections relevant to the code I wrote:

- [Let expressions](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#let-it-be)
- [Case expressions](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#case-expressions)
- [IO stuff](http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output#hello-world)
- [Functors](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids#functors-redux)
- [Monads](http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads)
- [More Monads](http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more)
- [Even More Monads](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Understanding_monads)

Oh, and to make your life easier, [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/).